# how to force Cache-Control to no-store in rails 3.2.20

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cache-control

There are several S.O. questions on this like:

- [Rails ( set_no_cache method) Cannot disable browser caching in Safari and Opera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744169/rails-set-no-cache-method-cannot-disable-browser-caching-in-safari-and-opera)
- [How to prevent browser page caching in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711418/how-to-prevent-browser-page-caching-in-rails)

But no mater what I do, what I override I'm still getting header (FireFox, Chrome, `curl -V`, ...any browser)

`Cache-Control: must-revalidate, private, max-age=0`

I tried

```
class ApplicationsController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :no_store_cache
  after_filter :no_store_cache

  def no_store_cache
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    response.headers["Expires"] = '-1'
  end
end
```

I Tried to call this callback directly on `ActionController::Base` (https://github.com/equivalent/no_cache_control.git )

I Tried digging in `rack-cache` middle-ware overriding stuff trying to enforce the header

I've created my own middleware that was overriding `header['Cache-Control']`.

nothing works

Comment: I've tested the `no_cache_control` gem  on one other project with rails 4.1 and it works but not on this Rails 3.2.20 project

Comment: https://github.com/equivalent/no_cache_control/issues/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Rails 3.2 the gem [`no_cache_control`](https://github.com/equivalent/no_cache_control) only works when the rails app is booted in production mode. Can test this by booting your app in production mode with:

`rails s -e production`

Note: make sure you have your `database.yml` pointing somewhere valid for the production environment.

Comment: ...hah, I'll be dammed, it works. Nice spot thank you for this

Comment: it works for my "Staging" environment too(pretty much duplicate of Producion). So the premiss is that due to some Development environment configuration it is ignoring it

Answer (score 0):

[Rails 7](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.2.4/actionpack/CHANGELOG.md#rails-700alpha1-september-15-2021) now has a `no_store` [method](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/07da73429a5fb7918556d16c7cdc5ea9f23d4a56).

```
before_action :no_store
```